# itertools.product pseudo-code

Tags: python

itertools [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) provides the following pseudo-code:

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

`map(tuple, args)` looks redundant: could simply use args. Am I missing something?

Here is my test code (python 2.7):

```
def product2(*args, **kwds):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = args * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)

print list (product(['A','B'],['C','D'])) == list (product2(['A','B'],['C','D']))
print list (product(['A','B'],['C','D'], repeat=2)) == list (product2(['A','B'],['C','D'], repeat=2))
print list (product([],[], repeat=2)) == list (product2([],[], repeat=2))
print list (product([])) == list (product2([]))

True

True

True

True
```

Comment: You are assuming that each argument is always a sequence; what if I passed in iterators instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's pass in iterators and see what happens:

```
>>> list(product(iter('AB'), iter('CD')))
[('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D')]
>>> list(product2(iter('AB'), iter('CD')))
[('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D')]
>>> list(product(iter('AB'), iter('CD'))) == list(product2(iter('AB'), iter('CD')))
False
```

Conclusion: you need to turn the arguments into tuples to capture all the values of the iterators.

It is even easier to illustrate when using only *one* iterator and the repeat option:

```
>>> list(product(iter('ABC'), repeat=2))
[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('C', 'C')]
>>> list(product2(iter('ABC'), repeat=2))
[]
```

Comment: print list (product(iter(['A','B']),iter(['C','D']))) == list (product2(iter(['A','B']),iter(['C','D']))) also does the trick

Comment: Yup, and using a string makes it more compact still. Updated with an extra example.